# Is it possible to solve a 2D relative motion question using components of relative velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, relative-motion

This is a question based on concepts of two dimensional motion . Here's how the question is:

> A plank A is floating in air, gravity has no effect on it (See its coordinates in the figure attached). At $t=0$ plank starts moving along the x-axis with an acceleration of $1.5 \ \mathrm{m/s^2}$. At the same instant a projectile is fired (see figure) from origin with a velocity $u$.
>
> A stationary person on ground observes the stone (projected particle) hitting the object during its downward motion at an angle of $45^\circ$ to the horizontal. Find the velocity with which the stone was fired. Also find the time after which stone hits the object. ($g=10\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$).
>
> [image: diagram of problem]

**TEXTBOOK APPROACH:**

$$\begin{gather}
s_x=u_xt=3+\frac12(1.5)t^2\tag{1} \\
s_y=u_yt-\frac12gt^2\quad\leftrightarrow 1.25=u_yt-\frac12gt^2\tag{2} \\
\tan 45^{\circ}         =\frac{-v_y}{v_x}=\frac{-(u-gt)}{u_x}\tag{3}
\end{gather}$$

These are now three equations in three variables and easily solvable.

I was however curious to know if we can solve this question using the concept of relative velocity seperately for x and y components like we do for 1-D Motion for the collision kind of questions? 
I tried but went horribly wrong but I am sure relative velocity in two different axes will also give us the right answer.

Comment: Hi Simar - as our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) says, we don't post complete solutions to homework-like questions (even if you already have another way to solve it!), but it's quite fine to just ask about methods, as I've edited the question to do.

Comment: The method you want to solve with will give the same equations, without any significant advantage at solving the math. For instance, you could choose the frame of reference of the plank, and apply an acceleration of $1.5 \mathrm{m/s^2}$ backwards on B. This will form another projectile motion, which you'll have to solve.

Comment: By doing LHS motion = RHS motion, is equivalent to relative motion = 0.